# Dividing an Dataframe by an measure with overlapping indexes results in NAN

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following Dataframe a and series b

[image]

[image]

```
a.div(b)
```

produces the following [image]

I was expecting the series/dataframe to be matched their indexes and for the operation to be carried out, what am I missing here ?

Comment: Please post raw text and code, also does `a.div(b, level=0)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a division, pandas attempts to match *both* the index and the columns. To get the answer you expect, you need to make sure the column names match. In short, use

```
a.div(b.rename(columns={'base_size':'persuasion'}))
```

You could also just divide the columns you're interested in; for example

```
a['persuasion'].div(b['base_size'])
```

Edit: here's a working example:

```
vals = ['nontriallist', 'triallist', 'user']
a = pd.DataFrame({'survey_components': 0,
                  'segment': 3 * vals,
                  'persuasion': 30 * np.random.rand(9)})
a = a.set_index(['survey_components', 'segment'])
b = pd.DataFrame({'survey_components': 0,
                  'segment': vals,
                  'base_size': 30 * np.random.rand(3)})
b = b.set_index(['survey_components', 'segment'])

a.div(b.rename(columns={'base_size':'persuasion'}))
```

output:

```
                                persuasion
survey_components segment                 
0                 nontriallist    0.177813
                  nontriallist    4.815070
                  nontriallist    4.812900
                  triallist       2.502781
                  triallist       0.532746
                  triallist       0.935246
                  user           11.527919
                  user            9.329557
                  user            0.986049
```